# How can I skip specific iterations in a for loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

Basically, I have a nested for loop. In the inner loop, something happens, and I can skip 3,4,5 or however many iterations i need skipped. But I can't do the same for the outer loop.
Hope that made sense.
Here is my code:

```
phraseArray = []
phraseArray2 = []
counterAdd = 0
counter = 0

try:
    for i in range(len(wordArray)):
        for j in range(len(wordArray2)):
            if wordArray[i]==wordArray2[j]:
                counter = 0
                counter2=3
                while True:
                    if wordArray[i+counter]==wordArray2[j+counter]:
                        counter = counter+1
                        if counter==3:                                           
                            phraseArray.append(wordArray[i+0])
                            phraseArray.append(wordArray[i+1])
                            phraseArray.append(wordArray[i+2])
                        elif counter>3:
                            phraseArray.append(wordArray[i+counter2])
                            counter2 = counter2+1
                    else:
                         phraseArray.append(" ")
                         j=j+counter
                         break

except IndexError:
    print phraseArray2
```

The j = j+1 is used to skip certain iterations. I cant do the same for the outer loop because the inner loop changes the counter variable which dictates how many iterations need to skipped. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance guys! :)

Comment: Maintain another `counter` for the outer loop, and use `i += counter` to skip?

Comment: You should simplify your code to the minimum necessary to reproduce your problem and be more explicit about the conditions under which you want to skip iterations. That said, you are probably interested in the [`continue` keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: Adding to `j` or `i` doesn't even accomplish anything, since those variables will be reset on the next iteration of the loop anyway.  This is not like a `for` loop in C or java.

Comment: what is the problem you want to solve with your code? I feel, there is a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd work with iterators here.

```
import itertools

def skip(iterable, n):
    next(itertools.islice(iterable, n, n), None)

outer_numbers = iter(range(...))
for i in outer_numbers:
    inner_numbers = iter(range(...))
    for j in inner_numbers:
        if condition:
            skip(outer_numbers, 3)  # skip 3 items from the outer loop.
            skip(inner_numbers, 2)  # skip 2 items from the inner loop.
```

Of course, you may want/need `continue` and/or `break` statements.

Comment: What is the islice method in function "skip"?

Comment: @ProSagramor -- sorry, should have been [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), not just `islice`.  (I copied too closely from the itertools consume recipe)

Answer (score 3):

A general form for skipping multiple iterations of a loop could work like this.

```
skips = 0
for x in y:
    if skips:
        skips -= 1
        continue

    #do your stuff

    #maybe set skips = something
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use "break" in the outer loop because this will finish the loop and not skip it, what you can do is use some IF statements to control the cases you want. something like

```
if(condition=skip):
   #do nothing
else:
  # do
```